# How can a form with tokenInput include qualifiers?

Tags: input, input-fields

I have a form for modifying songs in which you can add/remove links to artists with a special text field having [tokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) capability for auto-completion. This field looks like this:
[image: tokenInput enabled field for associating artists to a specific song]

Of course, the final version will not say **Artist wiki links text**, don't worry about that. My problem is that I want the user to be able to add descriptions to the relation between the song and the artists. So, for example, **McCartney, Paul** is a **composer** and a **bass-player** on that song, and **Lennon, John** is an **author** and **guitar-player**. Furthermore, these descriptions also need an auto-complete feature...

So the question is: How can I provide this to the user in a lean and intuitive way?

P.S If anyone can think of a better title for this question, I'm very much interested because I don't think my title is very good right now...

Answer (score 2):

I would try to separate these actions to lower user's confusion. Having to many cascaded dropdowns (and in general, any depending on each other elements) is always complicated to maintain from Ux prospective.

Hence, if you allow user to select the artists first in whichever way you prefer, then degroup that selection (within a new section on the page) and allow the editions for each of them in a list box manner (with *tokenInput* solution for each, actions to delete items and callback with notification to remove items from original selection if it was removed in a new one) - this will simplify the layout, I believe